# Issue facing in Css grid in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I hope all are doing well, I am working on WordPress I have written an HTML markup for grid where at single row 2 images are  need to show but the they are vertical showing each row a single image I want grid

```
    <div class="our-specialties Container">
            <h3 class="primary-text"> Pizzas </h3>
            <div class="container-grid">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'specialties',
                    'post_per_page' => 10,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'category_name'=> 'pizza' 
                    ) ;
                $pizzas  =  new WP_Query($args);
                while($pizzas->have_posts()): $pizzas->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="columns2-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('specialties');  ?>
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?><span><?php the_field('price');?></span> </h4>
                        <?php the_content();  ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();   ?>
            </div>
            <h3 class="primary-text"> Others </h3>
            <div class="container-grid">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'specialties',
                    'post_per_page' => 10,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'category_name'=> 'other' 
                    ) ;
                $pizzas  =  new WP_Query($args);
                while($pizzas->have_posts()): $pizzas->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="columns2-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('specialties');  ?>
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?><span><?php the_field('price');?></span> </h4>
                    <?php the_content();  ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();   ?>
            </div>
        </div>

code for the style sheet

@media only screen and (min-width:768px){

        .container-grid{
            margin-left: -10px;
            margin-right: -10px;
        }
        .container-grid::after{
            content:'';
            display: block;
            clear: both;

        }
        [class*='columns']{
            padding: 0 10px;
            float: left;
        }
        .columns2-4{
            width: 50%;
        }


    }
```

here the images are show single at each row means a vertical one by one images are there, let me know where i am making mistake code looks perfect, the above css codes with classes in html is described, any trick so to solve css

i am creating a menus section, i am following an author but he has different result for the same code i have different

Comment: Things to try: remove the 10px padding on `columns`; inspect your elements and see if `columns2-4` have any margin. It's very unlikely that anyone here could solve your problem because there are any number of other stylesheets involved. It would be a good time to learn how to inspect elements and troubleshoot your own CSS. :) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add **box-sizing: border-box;** to your column like this :

```css
.container-grid {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.container-grid::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

[class*='columns'] {
  padding: 0 10px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns2-4 {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="our-specialties Container">
  <h3 class="primary-text"> Pizzas </h3>
  <div class="container-grid">
    <div class="columns2-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
        <h4>title<span>20 $</span> </h4>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns2-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
        <h4>title<span>20 $</span> </h4>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns2-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
        <h4>title<span>20 $</span> </h4>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns2-4">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
        <h4>title<span>20 $</span> </h4>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```